# libGDX: Opening 3D scene from 2D screen

Tags: java, libgdx

Using libGDX I have created a few 2D screens, such as a splash screen and a main menu, and also created a 3D scene which I want to be able to load when clicking a button on the main menu.
I know how to add a listener but I don't know what command to use to show the 3D scene on the screen. If I use `setScreen(new World3D)` (or other similar extended methods) it gives me:
 `World3D cannot be cast to com.badlogic.gdx.Screen`

What I want to know is how to get from the 2D screen to the 3D scene. Do I wrap the 3D scene inside the screen or am I doing it right but my `World3D` class is not set up properly?
[Here](http://pastebin.com/GsqB4cVt) is a pastebin of my `World3D` class in case that is the problem.

NOTE: The classes are in separate sub-packages but the proper imports have been added in the required classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all a `Screen` is neither 2D nor 3D. It is just an interface. It's methods are usually called by the `ApplicationListener`, if something special (`pause`, `resume`...) happens.
Your problem here is, that you `World3D` is an `ApplicationListener`.
The `ApplicationListener` is the core of every Libgdx game, which gets notified by the backends, if some event occurs.
In your case it should be a `Screen` instead. You can simply set your `Game`s `Screen` to be the `World3D` `Screen`, and it's `render` method would be called.

I would suggest you to read the [Libgdx Wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki) before starting to create games.